# Split Columns into two equal number of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table structure below,

[image]

I need to merge the CouponNumber to two equal as CouponNumber1 and CouponNumber2 as shown in the figure

[image]

```
SELECT Name, MobileNumber, CouponNumber, IsDispatched, Status 
FROM CouponInvoicePrescription
```

This is my query.

Comment: You can resolve this by creating a separate RANK column that is grouped by Name, MobileNumber, etc. Then, you divide the RANK value by 2 and if the remainder is 0 / 1 will determine if its CouponNumber1 or CouponNumber2.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH
input(ord,name,mobno,couponno,isdispatched,status) AS (
          SELECT 0,'amar',8888888888,'CPever901',FALSE,1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'amar',8888888888,'CP00005'  ,FALSE,1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'pt3' ,7777777777,'cp9090'   ,FALSE,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'pt3' ,7777777777,'ev2'      ,FALSE,1
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'pt3' ,7777777777,'cp9909'   ,FALSE,1
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'pt3' ,7777777777,'cp10'     ,FALSE,1
)
SELECT
  name
, MAX(CASE ord % 2 WHEN 1 THEN couponno END) AS couponno1
, MAX(CASE ord % 2 WHEN 0 THEN couponno END) AS couponno2
, isdispatched
, status
FROM input
GROUP BY
  ord / 2
, name
, isdispatched
, status
ORDER BY 1

-- out  name | couponno1 | couponno2 | isdispatched | status 
-- out ------+-----------+-----------+--------------+--------
-- out  amar | CP00005   | CPever901 | f            |      1
-- out  pt3  | cp10      | cp9909    | f            |      1
-- out  pt3  | ev2       | cp9090    | f            |      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    sub.rn,
    sub.Name,
    sub.MobileNumber, 
    sub.CouponNumber as CouponNumber1, 
    LEAD(sub.CouponNumber,1) OVER (PARTITION BY sub.MobileNumber ORDER BY sub.rn) as CouponNumber2, 
    sub.IsDispatched, 
    sub.Status 
   FROM
  (
       SELECT  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by MobileNumber ORDER BY Name)  as rn, 
       * 
       FROM 
       input
    ) sub
) 
WHERE rn % 2 <> 0
```